# How can I put image inside parent div and it should be equal to bottom of div

Tags: html, css, position, display

[image]

Hello everyone!!
I am struggling to put this image inside the blue backgrounded div.
The image bottom should be equal to the parent div.
How can I solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!!!
HTML

```
 <div class="get-experience">
  <div class="get-exbg"></div>
  <div class="get-extext">
    <h2>Get experience from the expert</h2>
    <p>
      Quid ex eo ortum, tam inportuno tamque crudeli; sin, ut aliquid ex
    </p>
    <button>Contact Us</button>
  </div>
  <div class="get-exphoto">
    <img src="img/woman.png" alt="" />
    <div class="get-excircle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  .get-experience {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
}

.get-exbg {
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 120px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid #58bebf;
  border-bottom: 25px solid #58bebf;
  border-right-width: 1440px;
  border-bottom-width: 370px;
}

.get-extext {
  color: #fff;
  top: 50%;
  margin: auto 175px auto 165px;
  position: relative;
}

.get-exphoto img {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: margin-top or vertical align should align it at the bottom of the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .get-experience {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
}

.get-exbg {
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 120px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid #58bebf;
  border-bottom: 25px solid #58bebf;
  border-right-width: 1440px;
  border-bottom-width: 370px;
}

.get-extext {
  color: #fff;
  top: 50%;
  margin: auto 175px auto 165px;
  position: relative;
}

.get-exphoto img {
  position: relative;
}
.get-exphoto {
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-end;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="get-experience">
  <div class="get-exbg"></div>
  <div class="get-extext">
    <h2>Get experience from the expert</h2>
    <p>
      Quid ex eo ortum, tam inportuno tamque crudeli; sin, ut aliquid ex
    </p>
    <button>Contact Us</button>
  </div>
  <div class="get-exphoto">
    <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20190307/ourmid/pngtree-vector-programming-icon-png-image_757435.jpg" width="50px" alt="" />
    <div class="get-excircle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You solve this problem by add this at the end of your CSS file or style tag:

```
.get-exphoto {
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-end;
    }
```

this means that the parent of the img tag will have a flex display and any child inside with be aligned vertically to the end.

Comment: It's not working :(

Comment: @AyZed try the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you could add a codepen link but for what I can tell you need to add height 100% to your image like this:

```
.get-exphoto img {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This would only work if a parent element has a set height.